# Find a bisector point of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, analytic-geometry, triangles

The coordinates of $A=(x_{0},y_{0}$) and $B=(x_{1},y_{1}$) are given. How to find the coordinates of $C$ and $D$ as per given information below.

1. ABC is equilateral triangle such that $AB=BC=CA$
2. $\angle ADB=120^\circ$
3. CD line is the bisector line to $\angle ADB$,  such that $\angle ADC=\angle CDB=60^\circ$
4. The points $A,B,C,D$ all are in the same circle

[image]

Comment: Setting up (1) easiest part, depending on your method of construction. Construct the equilateral triangle $ABC$ by constructing the circles centred at $A$ and $B$, respectively, with radius $AB$. Pick one of the points of intersection and call it $C$. Connect them for your triangle.

From there, it is on you to make the circle $ABC$ using a similar sort of trick.

Comment: I just noticed you want the coordinates of the points. If you are allowed to use trigonometry, this becomes really easy. You could do it algebraically, but it gets a bit messy.

Comment: C lives on the perpendicular bisector of AB, and we know how far it is from AB (at least in terms of the given coordinates).  Once the circle is drawn, D is a red herring in that any point on the circular arc between A and B will work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to fix the coordinates of $D$ with the given information. In fact, $D$ could be any point on the small arc $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}$.

Given points $A$ and $B$, finding points $C$ and $O$ are not hard. But let's look at the requirements for $D$. Requirements (1) and (4) are met if we choose any point in the small arc $AB$.

The arcs $AC$ and $BC$ clearly have a central angle of $120°$ each, so the large arc $ACB$ has the central angle $240°$. Any angle on the circle that subtends that arc will have half that measure, $120°$. That satisfies requirement (2).

Then angle $\angle ADC$ subtends an angle of $120°$ and thus has a measure of $60°$, and the same is true for $\angle CDB$. That satisfies requirement (3).

Answer (score 0):

By an early Euclid's theorem property of circles the angle subtended at periphery D is half that subtended at center O. Angles

$$ CDB = \frac12 \cdot COB,ADC = \frac12 \cdot AOC $$

In other words *all* the bisectors at D meet at a *single focal concurring point* C.

You have picked a particular instance from  general situation, so there can be *no unique solution* or defining position for point D. Meaning, all points on minor arc AB equally well satisfy as solution position of D for stated conditions.